# get current year and five years before

Tags: php, date

I need a select tag with current year and five years before

```
<select class='selrange' id='rangeyeara'>
<?php
for($y=date("Y")-5; $y=date("Y"); $y++){
    echo "<option>" . $y . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

current year is there but there is no any other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second statement in your `for` loop need to be the "end" condition.

Change the operator `=` (assignation) to `<=` (comparison):

```
<select class='selrange' id='rangeyeara'>
<?php
for($y=date("Y")-5; $y<=date("Y"); $y++){
    echo "<option>" . $y . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the year is quite easy in PHP.

```
<select class='selrange' id='rangeyeara'>
<?php $currentYear = date('Y'); ?>
<?php for ($year = $currentYear - 5; $year <= $currentYear; $year++): ?>
    <option value="<?= $year; ?>"><?= $year; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```